# How to deploy web application in alfresco as i am newbie in alfresco

Tags: java

I have created web application in spring mvc and now i have to deploy it in alfresco but i don't know how to do it as i am new to alfresco and don't have much knowledge about it.i would be grateful if anyone helps me out.so that i get solution to my problem faster.

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you got any code you can share? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: i have created web application using spring mvc and created a war file of it.